# Difference of Divergent Series - Question Updated

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

If $\sum{a_n}$ and $\sum{b_n}$ are divergent infinite series, $\sum(a_n-b_n)$ may converge or diverge.

I am looking for interesting, nontrivial examples of both.

Context: I am teaching high school students with knowledge of differential and integral Calculus, who have recently been introduced to infinite series.

Comment: $a _ n = b _ n$

Comment: If you want $a_n$,$b_n$ to be different take $b_1=a_1-1,b_n=a_n \ \forall n \geq2.$ Or one counter example is $\sum \frac 1 n$,$\sum \frac 1 {n+1}$. That is $\sum \frac 1 {n(n+1)} \leq \sum \frac 1 {n^2}<+\infty$

Answer (score 0):

Counterexample: $a_n = b_n$

The [source](https://math.berkeley.edu/%7Ekmill/math1bfa15/11.2.note.pdf) contains useful theorems with regard to convergence and divergence of a sum of series, as well.